# pyautogui is delayed in .png searches/ going to next line of code too soon

Tags: python-3.x, delay, pyautogui

Okay I've gotten pretty far since I started this but I've been wondering about a few things I'd like to improve on.

So When the dell.com/support pops up it takes about 10 seconds for it to figure out where to click. (Lines 31-35) this ends up being an issue because sometimes the next part of the code starts running.

For example while #drivers and downloads is still being searched for it jumps to (ctrl+f "show all")

What can I do to decrease the delays? without just adding in more time.sleep(x) is there something I can set up for a wait until XYZ

```py
"""
Pip install list:

autogui
pyperclip
pillow
"""

import subprocess
import pyperclip
import re
import os
import pyautogui
import time


SerialNumber = 'wmic bios get serialnumber'
result = subprocess.getoutput(SerialNumber)
SerialResult = (result.strip("SerialNumber"))
print(re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "", SerialResult))
pyperclip.copy(re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "", SerialResult))

os.system("start chrome.exe --new-window dell.com/support")

screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size() #gets the size of Primary Monitor
currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position() #gets the XY position of mouse
print(" X: ",  currentMouseX, "Y: ", currentMouseY,"\n", "Width:",screenWidth, "Height:", screenHeight)

#searchbar
SearchBarLocation = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('SearchBar.PNG')
pyautogui.moveTo(SearchBarLocation)
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
pyautogui.press('enter')
print(1)
#drivers and download
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')
pyautogui.write('drivers & downloads')
DriversAndDownloadsLocation = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('DriversAndDownloads.PNG')
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.moveTo(DriversAndDownloadsLocation)
pyautogui.click()
print(2)
#find drivers
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')
pyautogui.write('Find drivers')
time.sleep(1)
FindDriversLocation = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('FindDrivers.PNG')
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.moveTo(FindDriversLocation)
pyautogui.click()
print(3)
#show all
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')
pyautogui.write('Show all')
time.sleep(1)
ShowAllLocation = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ShowAll.png')
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.moveTo(ShowAllLocation)
pyautogui.click()
print(4)
#Dell Update
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')
pyautogui.write('dell command | update application')
time.sleep(1)
DellUpdateLocation = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('DellUpdate.PNG')
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.moveTo(DellUpdateLcation)
print(5)
#Download
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')
pyautogui.write('Download')
time.sleep(1)
DownloadLocation = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Download')
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.moveTo(DownloadLocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to make `locateOnScreen` run quicker.  You can designate a region to search in and you can toggle the `grayscale` flag to be True.

If `SearchBar.png` always appears in the same area of the screen, you can use a tool in pyautogui to record the co-ordinates.  If you open a python shell and write

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.mouseInfo()
```

An application called MouseInfo will open up that will assist in recording the co-ordinates.  When designating a region for location onscreen, the format is `(left, top, width, height)`.

For example, if you knew `SearchBar.png` was reliably always appearing at 1142, 721 and was 160 pixels wide and 80 pixels high, you could use do this:

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('SearchBar.png', region=(1142, 721, 160, 80))
```

Optionally, you can also toggle grayscale onto that call to make it faster.

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('SearchBar.png', region=(1142, 721, 160, 80), grayscale=True)
```

If you **NEED** `SearchBar.png` to continue your script, and the process breaks without finding it, you can implement a technique called [Busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting).  Basically, keep checking for a condition and do not proceed until it is met.  The implementation of that would look something like this:

```
timer = 0
timeout_time = 60
search_bar_location= pyautogui.locateOnScreen('SearchBar.png')
while search_bar_location is None:
    if timer > timeout_time:
        print('Could not find the search bar in 60 seconds')
        exit(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    search_bar_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('SearchBar.png')
    timer += 1
# Searchbar is available if the code gets here
pyautogui.moveTo(search_bar_location)

...
```

It's generally good practice to not busy wait forever, that's why I've added the timer variables to exit the script after 60 seconds of busy waiting.

Comment: So far that sounds great definitely an improvement on what this code is doing. I'm curious though if I set each spot to a section of the screen will that mess up other computers with different screen dimensions? so like the screen I'm doing all the code and testing on is 1920x1080 and I'll be attempting to run this on by possibly sizes as small as something like1280x600. Again I do want to say thank you as the above suggestion is definitely leaps beyond where I was; I'll definitely take note of this moving forward for future codes

Comment: Yep, definitely, screen size is a very important thing to be thinking about if you're defining regions.  You can use `pyautogui.size()` to get the resolution of the display (e.g. for a 1920x1080 display you'll get (1920, 1080).  Depending on how consistent the image you're trying to locate is on, you can scale down/up regions proportionally.  But in general I think you'll find that approach to be fragile.

Comment: I've been looking into redoing this project in pycharm using selenium. I assume since it's searching based on the same locators this would be an option to get around the resolution issue? Currently the issue is my lack of understanding when I go to inspect the elements I'm running into issues with "element not found"

Comment: Depending on the usecase Selenium might make more sense.  Selenium won’t use co-ordinates or images to locate things, it’ll find them as they are rendered  in the browser.  So they are quite different approaches.

Comment: yeah I just haven't figured out how to read the "inspect" to write the codes. and I'm not really finding any resources to explain it several seem outdated as the code they use in the examples doesn't work